# Render html data in header and footer div in sequence

Tags: jquery, html

Currently in my html page i used two div to append html for header and footer.

Below is my code:

```html
<div id="headerSection"  class="tenantHeade fs-headerfooter-widget">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ReusableHeader.js"></script> 
</div>

<!-- Content Section --> 
<div class="content">
  <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
  This is a test content section
  <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
</div>

<!-- Footer Section --> 
<div id="footerSection" class="tenantHeaderWrap fs-headerfooter-widget">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="reusablefooter.js"></script> 
</div>
```

So, here in header section it is calling function inside .js file and appending html data for header `div`, same is happening for footer part also.

But what is happening is when I refresh my page first time header section is loading and second time refresh first footer section is loading.

Can we set something here so it should load first header section then footer section for every page refresh?

Comment: Why you are using two js for header and footer. You can use same js to load header and footer and its not a good habit to load js inside a div. Load the js in the header

Comment: I have requirement like the same. I can't use the different thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the `defer` attribute (see [MDN ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)) on the footer `<script>` tag.

It will delay the loading of the footer until the HTML is fully parsed. That way your header is likely run first.

```
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="reusablefooter.js"></script>
```

Comment: I used defer keyword in my footer script and when i refreshed my page so it is loading only header part. when i refreshed four five times then it started loading footer part instead of header. One more thing when it is loading either header or footer it stop loading second part, Like if first it is loading header then footer html is not getting load. if footer is loading then header is not getting load.